# Вычислить отношение произведения цифр натурального числа к их сумме

Tags: числа, c++

```
In
Первая строка стандартного потока ввода содержит количество тестов Т.
Каждый тест - заданное в отдельной строке натуральное N, не превышающее 2 ⋅ 109.
Out
Для каждого теста выведите в отдельную строку искомое отношение с точностью до 3-х цифр после десятичной точки.
Exm
_In__________Out____
2       |2.000     |
36      |2.000     |
63      |          |
--------------------
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){

    long long int T, i, j;
    long long int n, sum, mult;
    long long int h, a;
    long double k;
    float r;

    cin >> T;
    for (i = 0; i < T; i++) {
        cin >> n;
        sum = 0;
        mult = 1;
        while (n > 0){
            sum = sum + (n % 10);
            mult = mult * (n % 10);
            n = n / 10;
        }
        k = mult / sum;
        //r = mult / sum;
        printf("%.3lf\n", k);
        //printf("%.3lf\n", r);
        //cout << sum << endl;
        //cout << mult << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

_In__________Out____
63      |2.000     |
36      |2.000     |
18      |0.000     |
85      |3.000     |
--------------------
```

В чем проблема?!
Почему отношение 8 к 9 = 0?

Comment: Думаю, этот вопрос можно считать самым большим баяном в С++.

Дело в том, что вы делите одно целое число на другое. Целочисленные переменные (char, int, long и прочие)  не могут хранить дробную часть числа, поэтому при делении одного целого числа на другое выполняется тоьлко целочисленное деление без учета остатка. Чтобы исправить это, вам нужно  при делении хотя бы одно из чисел привести к float или double

Comment: Да, понял свою ошибку! Спасибо DreamChild и master_clown за помощь!

Comment: И не забывайте проверять, что введенное `n` больше нуля.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменная k у тебя double, но вот mult и sum - int. При делении остаток отбрасывается, а при делении меньшего на большее число и вовсе в 0 обращается. Рецепт: static_cast<double>( mult ).
Или sum, но привести ты должен один из них.